# JTree to String with hashs and arrays

Tags: java, arrays, string, parsing, jtree

I have a Jtree from a Hash where the object can be another hash or an array.
Now i need to take this JTree and convert it to String but i cant difference an array from a hash, how can I difference it?
Exists something like a tag in DefaultTreeNode with i could difference the nodes when i insert them on the JTree?

For example:

My Jtree is

```
>     Array
>         Hash1
>             String1
>             String2
>         Hash2
>             String1
>             String2
>             String3
>         Array1
>              String1
```

And the finally string must be

> [{String1, String2}, {String1, String2, String3}, [String1]]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for-loop to iterate each collection, and add each value to a new list of values.

```java
@SafeVarargs
List<List<String>> parse(Collection<String>... collections) {
    List<List<String>> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Collection<String> collection : collections)
        strings.add(new ArrayList<>(collection));
    return strings;
}
```

Example

```java
Set<String> hash1 = new HashSet<>(Set.of("abc", "def"));
Set<String> hash2 = new HashSet<>(Set.of("ghi", "jkl", "mno"));
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>(List.of("pqr"));
System.out.println(parse(hash1, hash2, list1));
```

Output

```
[[abc, def], [ghi, jkl, mno], [pqr]]
```